# Scala Play updating an XML request

Tags: xml, scala, playframework

I'm posting an XML to my Play application, and I want my controller action to look for a specific field, update the field value, and send it back.

Example XML:

```
<name>shrek</name>
<type>ogre</type>
<category>dank</category>
```

My controller action that just returns the same XML I'm posting:

```
def updateShrekXML() = Action(parse.xml) { request =>
    Ok(request.body)
 }
```

I've looked at the Play documentation but it is very limited, how can I return the XML with an updated field, for example changing `shrek` to `kek`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we didn't find much about `XML` parsing and updating in [Docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaXmlRequests).

But We can achieve this by considering `XML Node` as `Scala Class`

Here is a working example which works in your condition

**create a scala model for your XML object**

```
class SomeXML(var name: String, var itemType: String, var category: String){

  def toXML = { //converts to XML
    <xml>
      <name>{name}</name>
      <type>{itemType}</type>
      <category>{category}</category>
    </xml>
  }

  //we can also use setters / getters without writing XML node everytime. Just calling .toXML gives the node
  def updateName(newName: String) ={ //updates name
    <xml>
      <name>{newName}</name>
      <type>{itemType}</type>
      <category>{category}</category>
    </xml>
  }

  //some other utilities of your choice

}
```

**Same class object to deserialize XML**

```
object SomeXML {

  def fromXML(xmlNode: scala.xml.Node) = { //converts XML to Scala Object
    val name = (xmlNode \ "name").text
    val itemType = (xmlNode \ "type").text
    val category = (xmlNode \ "category").text
    new SomeXML(name, itemType, category)
  }

}
```

**Your Controller:**

```
  def updateXML() = Action(parse.xml) { request =>
    val originalXML = SomeXML.fromXML(request.body.head) //(.head) reads XML node from Node sequence
    val updatedXML = originalXML.updateName("YourName")
    Ok(updatedXML)
    //Output: YourName ogre dank
  }
```

In the same we can create `scala class` for every `XML request` and write your own utility functions to manipulate.

I'll update here if I found any Libraries or Utilities to do this in `play framework`.